# Why reverse Mishle verses' order?

Tags: torah-service, mishlei

When putting the Torah scroll back in its cabinet, we — at least most *Ashk'nazim* — say (among other things) "עֵץ חַיִּים הִיא לַמַּחֲזִיקִים בָּהּ וְתֹמְכֶיהָ מְאֻשָּׁר. דְּרָכֶיהָ דַרְכֵי נֹעַם וְכָל נְתִיבוֹתֶיהָ שָׁלוֹם.‏", which is *Mishle*, chapter 3, verses 18 and 17, in that order.

Similarly, when we — at least many *Ashk'nazim* — lift the Torah scroll after reading from it, we say (among other things) "עֵץ חַיִּים הִיא לַמַּחֲזִיקִים בָּהּ וְתֹמְכֶיהָ מְאֻשָּׁר. דְּרָכֶיהָ דַרְכֵי נֹעַם וְכָל נְתִיבוֹתֶיהָ שָׁלוֹם. אֹרֶךְ יָמִים בִּימִינָהּ בִּשְׂמֹאולָהּ עֹשֶׁר וְכָבוֹד.‏", which is *Mishle*, chapter 3, verses 18, 17, and 16, in that order.

Why do we reverse the order of the verses from the way they are in *Mishle*?

Comment: related: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/17179/song-while-dressing-the-torah?rq=1

Comment: http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=6822&st=&pgnum=378

Comment: @DoubleAA, fascinating, thanks. Why not post an answer?

Answer (score 3):

Rabbi Levi Yitzchok Raskin in his [notes](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=30450&pgnum=201) (397) on the [Baal Hatanya's](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shneur_Zalman_of_Liadi) Siddur, writes that these verses are out of order. He cites the [Siddur](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=22431&st=&pgnum=329) of [Rabbi Jacob Emden](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jacob_Emden) which does have the verses in the order of how they appear in Mishlei. He then cites the [Shaar Hakolel](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=16002&st=&pgnum=81), 22:7, (by Rabbi Abraham David ben Judah Leib Lavut, explains the reasons of the Baal Hatanya's emendations) which explains that the Baal Hatanya chose this order of the verses, because they are explained in this order in Pirkei Avos [Chapter 6 Mishna 7](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=34304&st=&pgnum=251). The Shaar Kolel states that Rashi's Pirush explains this order. It is interesting to note though that the text I cited leaves out "דְּרָכֶיהָ," while [other](http://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%9E%D7%A9%D7%A0%D7%94_%D7%90%D7%91%D7%95%D7%AA_%D7%95_%D7%96) texts include it at the end of the Mishna, which is not the order of the Baal Hatanya's Siddur. The Shaar Hakolel goes on to say that the [Tana Dvei Eliyahu Zuta](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=35934&st=&pgnum=54), chapter 17, also cites the verses in the order of the Baal Hatanya's siddur, again it is interesting to note that "דְּרָכֶיהָ" is also left out.

Answer (score 0):

I think it has to do with us blessing the person who is doing Hagbohas Hatorah, because he lifts up and holds the Atzei Chaim, we say to him "It (the Torah) is a tree of life to those that hold strong onto it".

In addition, it is in the order of things: First, you hold/cleave to the Torah. Second, its path through your life will be a peaceful one. Third, (the reward) you will benefit long life and wealth.